# How to change Rancher Desktop container IP range

Tags: rancher, rancher-desktop

By default every container in Rancher Desktop (using qemu) gets a 172.17.x.x IP.
This is problematic as I have other hosts on my regular intranet that also use  the 172.17.0.0/17 range. Therefore I can currently not reach any of those hosts from inside the docker container.

Is there something similar to the following I used with Docker Desktop's `daemon.json`:

```
{"default-address-pools": [ {"scope":"local", "base":"172.30.0.0/16", "size":24} ]
```